# How can I remove a HTML element when it goes below a certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that is centered in the middle of the screen. It is 1024*768 - part of a Windows 8 Metro app written in Javascript.

This div has a child element, a monster. That monster launches fireballs once every .5 seconds.

The monsters and the fireballs both move downward. I'd like to detect if either a monster or a fireball went below the bottom of the div.

How would I do that? I'm thinking maybe collision detection, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you controlling their movements? Assuming both have an x,y coord and some form of update/run method just add an if statement to the run method that checks whether or not the sprites next x/y coordinates is still within the div?

Something like:

```
 if(fireball.y > divnode.height) fireball.remove();
```

Comment: How would I add this to the run method of my fireball?

Comment: Not entirely sure how you've implemented your code, but I'm guessing the "run" method you'd want to use would be the same method your calling to update the position of the fireball (in order to move it down the page).

Comment: huh. I thought that it would be some method that was made automagically. I'll try that...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#monser').offset().top > Y-Coordinate || $('#monser').offset().top > Y-Coordinate){
    //FIRE YOUR ACTION HERE
}
```